# Changing DIV color in CSS depending on database results?

Tags: php, css

I want to change the background color of the DIV depending on some true/false values in the database I'm running. Can this be done in CSS or am I forced to use inline CSS when it comes to this?

One solution I came up with is that I had created several (4-5) classes to be called but the classes all had the same CSS rules except for the color and that just made me think that it was redundant and a waste of space.

I also researched and it seems that you can have PHP variables in CSS. BUT I would like to do it without making a separate .css/.php file to link in the header for several reasons. Is this possible?

**Maybe I can explain better with some code. Here is the concept I'm trying to get to and I want to know if I'm able to do it without an external stylesheet?:**

```
<hml>
<head>
div.content {
background-color: <?php echo $LegendColor;  ?>;
border-style:solid;
border-width:2px;
border-color: #000;
margin: 10px 0px;
}
</head>
<body>

<?php

/* After some database connection & query*/

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {


$var1 = $row["db_boolean_var1"];
$var2 = $row["db_boolean_var2"];
$var3 = $row["db_boolean_var3"];
$var4 = $row["db_boolean_var4"];

if($var1 == TRUE){
    $LegendColor = "#F00";
    }
    elseif ($var2 == TRUE){
        $LegendColor = "#F0F";
        }
        elseif($var3 == TRUE){
            $LegendColor = "#999";
            }
            elseif($var4 == TRUE){
                $LegendColor = "#0F0" ;
            }
                            else{
                                $LegendColor = "#FFF";
                                }




echo "<div class=\"content\">
</br>
</div>";

}

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not do

```
div.content {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color: #000;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

and then add an additional class to the div depending on the db result, e.g.

```
<div class="content <?php echo getContentClass($row) ?>"> ... </div>
```

where `getContentClass()` is a helper function that translates these boolean values into  meaningful CSS classes instead of the concrete color values.

```
function getContentClass(array $row)
{
    return implode(' ', array_intersect_key(
        array(
            'db_boolean_var1' => 'state1',
            'db_boolean_var2' => 'state2',
            'db_boolean_var3' => 'state3',
            'db_boolean_var4' => 'state4'
        ),
        array_filter($row)
    ));
}
```

Then just add those CSS classes to your regular stylesheet, e.g.

```
div.state1 { background-color: red; color: inherit }
```

This way, everything is cleanly separated and you dont have to resort to inline styles.

**Edit:** please note that class names like shown above are not meaningful. Nor are classnames like red or black meaningful because they are presentation related. Try to make them content related, e.g. something like invalid, error, paid, free, active and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I'll try to see which one of these suggestions works for me best. I'll come back whenever I'm done testing!

Comment: I have to say, this worked beautifully. Thank you so much! You get accepted answer for all your effort & being very thorough. :) Edit: I forgot to mention that the note for having meaningful CSS names match with the function of the database makes it more legible & understandable. Great tip!

Comment: Brillant! Brillant! Brillant! Brillant!

Answer (score 0):

You can use many classes for html elements so just the "color" class need to be changed.
To do this inline class is the best solution.

```
<element class="thing red" />

element.thing { general rules }

.red { color:red; }
```

Comment: Right, but in this case there will only be one boolean active (TRUE). There will never be more than one boolean marked as TRUE and my database structure has reflected that. The "else" is there just in case but won't be needed since all the variables are accounted for but I put it there just in case. I know I can use many classes but I thought there might be a better way since using a lot of classes with the same CSS rules seemed way too redundant. I was hoping there'd be a better solution than semi-redundant CSS classes.

Comment: I've edited sorry. But you can stock many booleans in an integer =P I often use many classes for my elements but I try to avoid redondant rules.

Comment: After reading your example what you said made more sense. Hmm. I will try this. Thanks for your suggestion, I'll come back and let you know the results.